# Update local branch after modified in master

Tags: git, git-merge

I have `master` branch. I created branch `A` based on `master`.
My teammate created branch `B` based on `master` too and he merged it into `master`.

I need a new data from branch `B` and I try to "rebase" branch `A` onto `master`, but git loses some commits and generates the wrong file when rebasing. No simultaneous changes have occurred in the same file (A has no conflicts with B). What could be the problem? How to update a branch without creating a mess in Git?

Comment: Check that you're not using an obsolete local ref. Either `git checkout master; git pull; git checkout branchB; git rebase master`, or `git checkout branchB; git fetch; git rebase origin/master`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say `branchB` is merged into `master`, then make sure to do the following:

`git checkout master` - that will switch local branch to master

`git pull origing` - that will pull latest changes from remote branch to local

`git checkout branchA` - switch to local branchA

`git rebase master`- rebase on master

But be aware, that `branchA` will still show you only local commits in history. It will not show commits from `branchB` - although, if rebase is successful, then it will contain all the changes from merged `branchB`. And this is because how rebase works - it takes every commit from `branchA`, and replays them on `master`. Kinda if you would have first merged `branchB` to `master`, and then created `branchA`, and did commits.